# HTML / CSS facebook links

Tags: html, css

I am currently studying HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT. I am struggling with positioning specifically and wondered if anyone can help. I have a fixed background image in my header (html and css) below.

HTML

```
<header>
    <h1>GEORGES BAR & GRILL</h1>
    <div>
        <section id="intro" />
        <img src="/Users/stewartlight/Documents/Stews_Stuff/Uni/SP3/GBAG/Images/restaurant_1.jpg" />
        </section>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#intro img {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 960px;
   height: 500px;
}
```

I am trying to add 'facebook' and 'twitter' image links. I am struggling to get the links to sit on the background and position to top right. If anyone can assist i would be much appreciated.

Comment: got a link on jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stewart1290/TZLRg/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stewart1290/TZLRg/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

You want  the position of the images to be `"position:absolute;"` and you want the containing div to have a `"position:relative;"` that's just how absolute  positioning is done. You must declare what you are positioning it relative to and then set what you what positioned absolutely to `"position:absolute;"`